# Сохранение данных, вывод в TextView и дальнейшая их обработка

Tags: java, android, textview, mobile-development, android-shared-preferences

Хочу создать калькулятор подсчета калорий употребленных за день. Смог прописать сохранение результат одной сессии. Но если я захожу еще раз, провожу расчет и сохраняю, то старый результат заменяется новым. А как их суммировать? Попробовал прописать так (пример в коде) - выдает ошибку и закрывает приложение. Может кто подсказать?

```
public class ActivityCalc extends AppCompatActivity {

// имя файла настроек
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "SettingsCalc";
// результат
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_RESULT = "ResultCalc";

SharedPreferences mResultCalc;

EditText etPaste;
EditText etChicken;
EditText etMilk;
EditText etBuckwheat;

Button btnPaste;
Button btnChicken;
Button btnMilk;
Button btnBuckwheat;
Button btnNewProd;

TextView tvResult;
TextView tvAllResult;

double weightPaste, weightChicken, weightMilk, weightBuckwheat;
double resultPaste, resultChicken, resultMilk, resultBuckwheat, resultDay;
double result = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);

    // находим элементы
    etPaste = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPaste);
    etChicken = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etChicken);
    etMilk = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMilk);
    etBuckwheat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBuckwheat);

    btnPaste = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPaste);
    btnChicken = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChicken);
    btnMilk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMilk);
    btnBuckwheat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuckwheat);
    btnNewProd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewProd);

    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    tvAllResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAllResult);

    mResultCalc = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Bзвлечения данных
    if (mResultCalc.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_RESULT)) {
                // выводим данные в TextView
                tvAllResult.setText(mResultCalc.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_RESULT, ""));
                String strResultDay = tvAllResult.getText().toString();
                resultDay = Double.parseDouble(strResultDay);
            }
}

// метод для расчета при нажитии кнопки
public void clickProd(EditText i, double a, double b, double c) {
    if (i.getText().length() == 0){
        i.setError("Заполните пустое поле");
    } else {
        a = Double.parseDouble(i.getText().toString());
        c = a * b;
        result = result + c;
        tvResult.setText(" " + result);
        resultDay = resultDay + result;
        tvAllResult.setText(" " + resultDay);
    }
}

// определяем нажатую кнопку
public void clickPaste(View v) {
    clickProd(etPaste, weightPaste, 2.88, resultPaste);
}

public void clickChick(View v) {
    clickProd(etChicken, weightChicken, 1.61, resultChicken);
}

public void clickMilk(View v) {
    clickProd(etMilk, weightMilk, 0.43, resultMilk);
}

public void clickBuckwheat(View v) {
    clickProd(etBuckwheat, weightBuckwheat, 1.37, resultBuckwheat);
}

public void clickNewProd(View v) {

}

// кнопка сохранения "Суммы"

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        // Кнопка сохранения данных
        case R.id.btnSave:
            // здесь содержится текст, введенный в текстовом поле
            String strResult = tvAllResult.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mResultCalc.edit();
            editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_RESULT, strResult);
            editor.apply();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Process: com.example.fitness_application, PID: 6345
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fitness_application/com.example.fitness_application.ActivityCalc}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "Сумма: 64.4"
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "Сумма: 64.4"
                                                                                   at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                   at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
                                                                                   at com.example.fitness_application.ActivityCalc.onCreate(ActivityCalc.java:69)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Много лишнего кода в вопросе - вряд ли инициализация вьюх нужна в вопросе. Также нужно сообщение об ошибке и строка возникновения. По сути - если вы считаете в числа - не пишите строки в префы. Пишите числа. Тогда перед записью их можно получить, приплюсовать что-то и заново записать увеличенную сумму.

Comment: вам нужно отказаться от SharedPreferences, так как они совсем не предназначены для такого использования и сделать сохранение в БД, SQLite или ORM, вроде Realm (предпочтительнее для вашего случая). Каждая запись (строка в БД) будет одной сессией. Сама БД предоставляет все возможности по сбору статистических данных из записей собственными инструментами (запросами в БД). Так же, как уже сказали, если вы хотите складывать числа - сохраняйте числа, а не строки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: вы пытаетесь строку "сумма:64.4" превратить в число, но буквы это не цифры и такое преобразование невозможно, о чем вам и пишут

Comment: @pavlofff, понял. Буду исправлять. Спасибо.